# Is there a good measure of "paternless-ness" in a set of data?

Tags: pattern-recognition, noise

This may be a slightly open-ended question, or even a bad one, but are there any measures of looking at a set of data and seeing whether there is any kind of pattern or not?

For some context my question is specifically related to looking at fit residuals, as I always thought a good measure of a fit is how patternless the fit residuals are. In some cases one can do this just by eye -- but it is always nice to quantify such things -- especially for automation and batch fitting.

I considered looking at auto-correlation functions, but as I understand them these are more relevant for time dependant data sets.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the 'fit residual' part?

Comment: Sure, if you simply take your data and then subtract the fit from the data. What is left over should just be noise, assuming you have a good model. If your model or fit is bad you will see a pattern emerge in the fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot feasibly prove there is *no* pattern period. That would require evaluating over *all the possible patterns*, which is to the best of my knowledge an infinite space.

If you constrain the problem to a specific subset of possible patterns, this *may* be tractable, but it's not a given even then.